# Is there a way to combine data values from collection into a single string?

Tags: powerapps

I've tried patching my collection to SP list. However, it creates new item for every row from my collection. What I wanted to achieve is to combine all data from the collection and insert it as a single entry in Sharepoint.

I've created a button that patches the data from collection to SharePoint.

```
ForAll(RemedialCollection,Patch(CAF,Defaults(CAF),{Title:title_datavalue.Text, RemedialAction:RemedialAct,RemedialActionDetails:RemDetails}))
```

However, this function creates new item per row. For example in my collections I have 3 entries, when I patch it, I will have 3 new entries in SP. Is it possible to combine those 3 entries into 1 entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can first use the [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) function to combine the same fields of the entries, then use Patch to patch the data into SharePoint. However Concat creates strings so it may not match the data type for all your SharePoint fields. There is a PowerApps discussion where someone [uses Concat to combine records to speed up the Patch function](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Combine-rows-in-collection-separated-by-commas-so-that-Patch/td-p/163877).

You could also look at this discussion about [combining records inside of a collection](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Combining-Multiple-Records-to-One-via-a-collection/td-p/63776).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to patch an entire table to a single field.

Like drvela suggested, you'll likely need to concatenate the content into a string that you can save.

That being said, I would not suggest saving a tables worth of data into a single field. Fields have limitations on the number of characters they can include and the data is not as searchable by column when you attempt to save it this way.

Instead, what you may want to learn more about is setting up relations between tables. This way your CAF table can include an ID number for each remediation. And another table can reference that ID for every remediation action that has been taken. This is an example of 1:many relationship: 1 remediation ID to many remediation actions.